# Adherence and compactness

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let be $(S,\mathcal{S})$, $(T,\mathcal{T})$ topological spaces for which the first is compact and the last is a Hausdorff space. If $f:S\rightarrow T$ is a continuous function show that $\overline{f(X)}=f(\overline{X})$ for all $X\subseteq S$.

I don't know what I'm not seeing, because I try to prove it but I'm not sure where to use the fact that $(S,\mathcal{S})$ is compact.

I will be very grateful to anyone who can give me some hint or guide me in the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\overline{X}$ is a closed subset of a compact set $S$, so it's compact too. Since $f$ is continuous, we have that $f(\overline{X})$ is compact. A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed, so $f(\overline{X})$ is closed. Since $X\subseteq\overline{X}$, we have that $f(X)\subseteq f(\overline{X})$. Therefore $\overline{f(X)}\subseteq f(\overline{X})$.